# Help Convert C# code to Vb 8.0

Tags: c#, vb.net

.

```
 private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

               List<CaclulatedData> tests = new List<CaclulatedData>
                                   {
                                    new CaclulatedData()
                                     {
                                      Bonds = "First Bond",
                                      TransactionList = new List<TransactionData>
                                                {
                                                 new TransactionData() {Debit = "DebitData"}
                                                }
                                     },
                                    new CaclulatedData()
                                     {
                                      Bonds = "Second Bond",
                                      TransactionList = new List<TransactionData>
                                                {
                                                 new TransactionData() {Debit = "123123"},
                                                 new TransactionData() {Debit = "12312", Credit = "3453"}
                                                }
                                     }
                                   };
               gridControl1.DataSource = tests;

    }

}
public class JEString
{

    public string Bonds { get; set; }

}

public class CaclulatedData : JEString
{
    public List<TransactionData> TransactionList { get; set; }
}


public class TransactionData
{
    public string Debit { get; set; }
    public string Credit { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: "It's all been done before"
- Unknown

Comment: Nice quotation. And as for those who putting minuses: if person only begin to study unfamiliar field and have the direct problem what has he to do in order to obtain the knowledge? Google and Books? But what about simple Human help? Nevertheless thanks for good answers. They were helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Part of your problem is that vb8 does not yet support some of the features your C# code is using (automatic properties and collection initializers, for example), so the translations is not 1:1.  Some of these features were added in VB9.  That said, it's not that hard:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    Dim tests As New List(Of CaclulatedData)(2)

    tests.Add(New CalculatedData())
    tests(0).Bonds = "First Bond"
    tests(0).TransactionList.Add(New TransactionData())
    tests(0).TransactionList(0).Debit = "DebitData"

    tests.Add(New CalculatedData())
    tests(1).Bonds = "Second Bond"
    tests(1).TransactionList.Add(New TransactionData())
    tests(1).TransactionList(0).Debit = "123123"
    tests(1).TransactionList.Add(New TransactionData())
    tests(1).TransactionList(1).Debit = "12312"
    tests(1).TransactionList(1).Credit = "3453"

    gridControl1.DataSource = tests
End Sub

Public Class JEString
    Private _Bonds As String
    Public Property Bonds() As String
       Get
          Return _Bonds
       End Get
       Set(ByVal value As String)
           _Bonds = value
       End Set
    End Property
End Class

Public Class CaclulatedData 
    Inherits JEString

    Private _TransactionList As New List(Of TransactionData)()
    Public ReadOnly Property TransactionList() As List(Of TransactionData)
        Get
            Return _TransactionList
        End Get
    End Property
End Class


Public Class TransactionData
    Private _Debit As String
    Private _Credit As String

    Public Property Debit() As String
       Get
          Return _ Debit
       End Get
       Set(ByVal value As String)
           _ Debit = value
       End Set
    End Property

    Public Property Credit() As String
       Get
          Return _ Credit
       End Get
       Set(ByVal value As String)
           _Credit = value
       End Set
    End Property
End Class
```

Answer (score 3):

You could also, use reflector to convert your .net assembly into any of the below languages.

- IL
- C#
- VB.NET
- Delphi
- MC++

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of free online C# to VB.NET and VB.NET to C# converters available:

http://converter.telerik.com/

http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/vb-to-csharp/

http://www.kamalpatel.net/ConvertCSharp2VB.aspx

http://www.carlosag.net/Tools/CodeTranslator/